# UIAlertController of style ActionSheet shows below status bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uiactionsheet

I want to show an alert controller of style action sheet to display the list of states in a country and that works fine.

[image]

But for some weird reason it shows action sheet below status bar partially which is not acceptable as it looks bad, how ever I can remove the status bar when displaying the action sheet which should work.

So I was just wondering is there any other way to make the action sheet stop to a particular offset from the top. I tried presenting the action sheet from the navigation controller but nothing changed.

Any comments appreciated.

Thanks,
Robin.

Comment: I think it's not below the status bar. It's just large, so it complete whole your screen

Comment: The list scrolls in that area only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var height:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: alertController.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 300)
alertController.view.addConstraint(height);
```

Set it height to `300`. Look, will it do any changes?

Comment: Nope, for action sheet with less options it moves up